Yoshino cherry tree sapling care (6 in or so)
i've just received my little Yoshino sapling (roughly 6 in) and the seller didn't bother giving me care instructions. I reaaaally don't want it to die, so i was hoping someone could help me do things properly. Is it okay to keep it inside until it's grown a bit bigger or should I put it in the soil outside immediately? I live in the province of Quebec (Canada) and we have cold winters, but we're a zone 5 (so i think it's supposed to survive winter). Thanks in advance for your help! :)

If it's intended to be an outside tree, the sooner you get it in the ground the better. At 6 inches/15cm tall give it some protection from deer and rabbits (etc.) with a wire cage staked around it. Fine mesh "hardware cloth" will also protect from mice, etc. gnawing the bark in the winter.
When you transplant:
Do. Not. Change. The. Soil. Level.
Probably the commonest way to kill trees.
Also, avoid making a "hole of improved soil" to plant the tree in. That has a tendency to backfire and cause the roots to stay put there, rather than dealing with the soil that is where the tree is planted and growing out into it.
Water regularly after planting whenever it does not rain. Shape the soil where it's planted to be a dish to contain water, perhaps 12-18" diameter for such a small tree, and stop watering when it starts to puddle. When it's dry for ~1/2" depth, water again if rain is not in the immediate future. This is only needed the first year after planting, normally, if not in a particularly arid climate (you're not.) They need help getting the roots established and getting adequate water while they do. Don't drown it, though.
Keep the area around the tree clear of grass - mulch out to the circle the ends of the branches imply. As the tree grows, the mulched area should also grow.
Plan for the full size of the tree when picking a spot. Transplanting after making a mistake is often possible, but always traumatic (for the tree. Possibly also for you.)
